# Fixed Slice Colors of a pie chart in Report

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

I have an Access report with several Pie charts (placed in a `GroupFooter`). Access doesn't select unique colors for each slice category, which make the charts incomparable.

For example: in the first chart the slice for `"Apple"` is red, in the next Chart it's blue.

Each chart consists of five categories (let's say Apple, Orange, Lemon, Strawberry, Raspberry). If one category is zero, it's not shown in the chart. To make the charts comparable, I'd like to predefine the category colors.

I tried several codes that I found in the internet, but none of them works for me. Last one I tried was:

```
Private Sub Report_Current()
    ChartName.SeriesCollection(1).Points("Apple").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 51, 0)
    ChartName.SeriesCollection(1).Points("Orange").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 117, 117)
    ChartName.SeriesCollection(1).Points("Lemon").Interior.Color = RGB(197, 90, 17)
    ChartName.SeriesCollection(1).Points("Strawberry").Interior.Color = RGB(244, 177, 131)
    ChartName.SeriesCollection(1).Points("Raspberry").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using your code in the `OnLoad` function of the the form containing the graph and use numerical indexes instead of the name of the points. I.E: `.Points(1).` I am getting issues referencing the Points by name on my end. Perhaps it would resolve your issue as well.

Comment: I have code in Format event for this. However, I use point index, not data value.

Comment: Pie charts with more than three slices should be avoided. Use horizontal bar charts instead. Solves a lot of issues. One color, no legend, just information. For more info read https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf

Comment: Hi everybody, thx for your comments. I tryed using numerical indexes as well, but it didn’t work for me neither. Besides, as 0-values are not represented in the charts, I think numercial indexes wouldn’t solve the problem, that same categories receive different colors across groups. 
@hisoka, unfortunately I don’t know the OnLoad function, could you describe in more detail how I should use it?
Thx teylyn for your advice, but I need to display the distribution of categories relative to each other, thats why I need a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation of what I mentioned in the comments...

For the sake of example, I created a blank form and added a pie graph from some random table.

[image]

In design view, on the property sheet, I added an `OnLoad` event to the form.

[image]

I added the following code and chose the same color for all three slices (Note that `Graph1` is the name of my graph from the property sheet) :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Graph1.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 117, 117)
    Graph1.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 117, 117)
    Graph1.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 117, 117)
End Sub
```

When I open the form I see the following :

[image]

Hopefully, this might help resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. I have no idea what I am doing wrong but no code works for me. The debugger always opens. I did exactly what you decribed. I created a new blank form and added a pie chart, which displays some data from a table. I named the pie chart "Graph1", just like yours. Than I added your code to the form for OnLoad. I than closed the form. Whenever I opened it again, the debugger opens, saying: "Error 438, object does not support this property or method." When I open the debugger, it marks the first code line ("Graph1.Series...")  :(

Comment: It's really strange... I also tryed some code from the Microsoft Website (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.point.markerbackgroundcolor), but that does also not work. Error 424: Object not defined. The Debugger marks the word "Charts".

Comment: I feel like it's an issue about my Access Version or so (which should be the latest version...I got Office 365), because I tryed several codes on my chart now and none of them worked...One other code I tryed: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/change-color-pie-chart-s-t1955875.html

Comment: Hi Jeanette, as far as I know, you should still be able to change the color regardless of your Access version. But from the error message that you are getting, it would seem that it can't find your chart. Perhaps, try checking you have the correct name or even try prefixing the graph with the form name. I.E: `Form_form1.Graph1.` If this does not work, do you think you could upload a version of your file somewhere so I can take a look at it? Make sure to remove any sensitive databefore you do so!

Comment: Hi hisoka, I tryed prefixing the graph, but unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem neither. I tryed some other code, to figure out if it can find the graph, and actually it does: 
`Private Sub Form_Load()
For Each ch In Form_ChartFruits
    MsgBox ch.Name
Next
End Sub`
-->This code worked well

Comment: However I think I found the problem, even though I have no idea how to fix it. I found that the library "Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library", which contains the Graph functions e.g. seriescollection, points etc. (found that Info in the internet) wasn't activated in my Database. However, although I than activated the library, the functions still didn't work. Than I proved the path of the Graph library (which is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Office\Root\Office16\GRAPH.EXE") and surprisingly the path doesn't exist on my computer.... :/

Comment: If you still think it helps, I can email you a sample database :)

Comment: Well, that sure is odd. I have the same version of the library, and I could locate the path to the `graph.exe` for mine in the references section. I used to have `MISSING` library references because I developed apps using different versions of Access, but I could simply choose an older version of that same library from the list and everything worked fine after. If that's not available to you either, then I am afraid I am completely clueless. Sorry :(

Comment: Going out on a limb here ... Perhaps you could try adding a reference to `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library`. Excel uses the same graph collection as well (series, points, chartobject).

Comment: It's been over a year now and I still can't solve the problem. I have the latest Access version now, but it still doesn't work on my computer, or any other I've tried. I think Access still has problems assigning the SeriesCollection function to the Graph library, but the latest Code I've tried doesn't work either:

Dim cht as Graph.Chart

Set cht = Me.mychart.Object

With cht
.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 51, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 51, 0)

End With
End Sub

Any other ideas? I mean, there must be solution! :(

Answer (score 0):

The graph/chart abilities changed significantly with Access 365. Code that works with the old graph component likely won't work in Access 365.

The new version uses a collection called ChartSeriesCollection, like this example:

```
With myChart.ChartSeriesCollection.Item(0)
 .BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 .FillColor = RGB(210, 250, 210)
End With
```

Here is the Microsoft article that describes the collection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.chartseries.fillcolor